# Building a MTurk-like app -- how to use a db when column names change for each task?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nosql, mechanicalturk

I'm building a very simple MTurk-ish app in Rails. The idea is that people will upload csvs containing whatever columns they want (e.g., some id, name of a user, some piece of text, a link, whatever -- these columns will change from task to task), and these csvs will contain all the information for the MTurk task.

My question is: how would I store these csvs in a database? One way is to store each csv row as a blob of unstructured data in MySQL (i.e., I basically leave each row as a string and stick this into a MySQL column). A maybe better way is to use a NoSQL database like MongoDB, where I don't need a predefined schema.

Suggestions? Which way is better, or is there another option? I am using Rails for this, so options that work well with Rails would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you pretty much answered your own question.

Either use a NoSQL Document based database (like MongoDB) or split up the cvs and save it in a 1:n correlation within your database as key value pairs attached to a row and column each. your idea to store blobs isn't quite ideal however as it would restrict you from searching within the columns.